# HIVE: Get all records where preceding record (by timestamp) is a specific value

Tags: sql, hive, windowing

I am doing pathing analysis where I need to see where one page leads to. How do I write a query that gets me all the records that have a preceding record of a specific value.

For example:

```
col1 timestamp
a    1   
b    2
a    3
c    4
b    5
e    6
```

I would want to return only c and b

I am trying to use windowing functions to do this but I have no experience with them and have completely failed :-(

Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use the `lag()` function . . . and a subquery:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, lag(col1) over (order by timestamp) as prev_col1
      from t
     ) t
where prev_col1 = 'a';
```

Comment: This looks like what I am looking for but when I run it I can en error due to "Unsupported complex type: MAP". Any ideas of what this could be?

Comment: I figured it out. The field is a map field which is not supported for windowing functions. Putting it into a sub query fixes that and then your answer works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Lead and Lag functions of Oracle will help you to achieve your expected results.

[Examples](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/lag.php)